# Registering Flutter plugins in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, background-process, dart-isolates

I'm using hive and path provider on different isolate, when I try to access them I'm getting **MissingPluginException**, I'm trying to register these plugins manually but not sure how to do it. Can anyone help me in solving the issue

Thank's in advance,

Comment: Were you able to solve this?